# How to send video in the rabbitmq cloud with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

So I tried sending normal text messages, they work fine, but when I try to send a video to the rabbitmq cloud, it successfully created the new queue but the queue shows empty:-

```js
import {Router} from 'express';
let router = Router();
import env from 'dotenv';
import amqp from 'amqplib';
import fs from 'fs';
env.config();
const videoData = fs.readFileSync('test/venice.mp4');
async function sendMessageToQueue(queueName, message) {
    try {
      // Connect to RabbitMQ
      const connection = await amqp.connect(process.env.RABBITMQ_URL);
      const channel = await connection.createChannel();
  
      // Assert a queue to ensure it exists
      await channel.assertQueue(queueName, { durable: true });
  
      // Send a message to the queue
      channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(message), {persistent: true});
  
      console.log(`Sent message to queue ${queueName}: ${'message'}`);
  
      // Close the connection and channel
      await channel.close();
      await connection.close();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending message to queue:', error);
    }
  }

router.get('/hello',async (req,res)=>{
    res.send(`lets send`);
    sendMessageToQueue('venice', videoData);
    
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ creates a new queue automatically when a producer or a consumer tries to publish or consume messages from a queue that does not already exist. This is a default behavior of RabbitMQ.

When a producer sends a message to a non-existing queue, RabbitMQ automatically creates a new queue with a generated name and binds it to the default exchange. The message will then be published to this new queue.

Similarly, when a consumer tries to consume messages from a non-existing queue, RabbitMQ automatically creates a new queue with a generated name and starts delivering messages to it. The consumer can then retrieve the messages from this new queue.

To prevent the automatic creation of queues, please make sure a valid queue is being passed.
Also you can use the passive parameter when declaring the queue. If the queue already exists, it will be used; otherwise, an error will be returned.

```
  // Declare a queue without allowing automatic creation
  const queue = 'my-queue';
  const options = { passive: true };
  const result = await channel.assertQueue(queue, options);
```

Comment: How does this answers the question I asked?

Comment: You mentioned it created a new queue.

Comment: @Darwin Swartz what question? try to ask something. Your text have not a single question mark at all.

Comment: @riyas ... and the Sarcastic Oscar goes to .... I wish I had the patience to write such a long text just to be sarcastic.